# Is it possible for a website hosted online to access the database on a local server?

Tags: database, hosting, web-hosting

To contextualize, I have locally developped a website connected to a database which is located on a local server. The next step is to host it online. Will I be able to access this database when my site is hosted ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you could do it If you open your router ports and you expose your network to the internet, however, that’s not recommended in any case. I would recommend you to host the database too.

Comment: Hosting the database does not seem to be the right solution in my case since it is the database of the company.
I thought about using a hosted database that would copy the needed data from the local databse. Is it a safer solution ?

Comment: Maybe you could sync the local database and mirror the content to a hosted one to be used in the website, the only problem of that the sync could not be easy.